# Kalman Filter implementation for one dimensional vector

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, filtering, kalman-filter

I am having an hard time figuring out something really stupid I think.

I want to refresh my kalman filter knowledge but I am not able to make it work.

In a simple case with 
real states x:

```
x = [   1000    750 563 422 316 237 178 133 100 75]';
```

and observations

```
z_array = [ 1056    943 469 235 433 230 116 136 -75 267]';
```

I get something really nice (*estimated* stands for FILTERED):

[image]

When instead I use another signal, more complex. I don't know why but it doesn't work (*estimated* stands for FILTERED).

[image]

The problem, I am quite sure is in how I choose the `a` and `r` in my code for the second case. But how can I change them?

Here is the short code I have written in MATLAB and I am getting lost (I am really ashamed because I should know how to do this!!).

```
close all

z_array = noisyMeas.signals.values;
x = meas.signals.values;

a = 0.75;
r= 200;
p=1;

% x = [ 1000    750 563 422 316 237 178 133 100 75]';
% z_array = [   1056    943 469 235 433 230 116 136 -75 267]';

xhat_array = zeros(length(z_array),1);
xhat = z_array(1);
xhat_array(1) = xhat;

% Core of the Kalman Filter 
for k=2:length(x)
    z = z_array(k);

    % Predict
    xhat = a * xhat;
    p    = a * p * a;

    % Update
    g    = p  / (p  + r);
    xhat = xhat + g * (z - xhat);
    p    = (1 - g) * p;
    xhat_array(k) = xhat;
end

% plotting
figure
hold on
plot(xhat_array,'r')
plot(x,'b');
plot(z_array,'g')
grid on
legend('estimated','notNoisy','Noisy')
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might want to consider the covariance for the process noise as well. I tested it with `p    = a * p * a + q;` and `q=10e5`, and the Kalman Filter estimated my cosine signal well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I tried what you said but it happens that the filtered signal is the same of the unfiltered one. 

Could you tell me more in the specific how did you that?